# Configuring SQL Server Profiler

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, sql-server-profiler, azure-analysis-services

I need to configure Profiler to save logs from an Analysis Server and save this data to a table on SQL Server daily. The problem is that every hour it stops working. How do I configure it correctly to not have this problem?

Comment: Profiler is deprecated, I wouldn't suggest using it for new implementations.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.